# What is the best way to check if a record already exists in database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm wondering what is the best way to check existence of an object before it's creation ?

I want to store search queries but it doesn't make sense to create a new one everytime if there's already one in database. I'd rather increment a counter to have stats about most common queries.

My biggest problem is how do I check if the object is already in base. I want to know if there is some magical function to check this without pulling out the whole table and checking if one of the objects equals the new one ?

Also, it really has to be on the form `find_or_create( myObject )` and check if all the attributes are the same (and I have a lot on each query object) and ignore `id` of course.

So this means I can't use a `find_or_create_by_region_id_and_departement_id_and_other_attr`

Ah and I'm working with Rails 3.2.6 :)

Any idea how to do this ?

Edit to add table structure for search queries :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: search_queries
#
#  id                 :integer(4)      not null, primary key
#  region_id          :integer(4)
#  departement_id     :integer(4)
#  ville              :string(255)
#  environnement_id   :integer(4)
#  etoiles_min        :integer(4)
#  etoiles_max        :integer(4)
#  tente              :boolean(1)
#  caravane           :boolean(1)
#  campingcar         :boolean(1)
#  mobilhome          :boolean(1)
#  chalet             :boolean(1)
#  bungalow           :boolean(1)
#  yourte             :boolean(1)
#  roulotte           :boolean(1)
#  tipi               :boolean(1)
#  autres             :boolean(1)
#  wifi               :boolean(1)
#  restaurant         :boolean(1)
#  epicerie           :boolean(1)
#  depotpain          :boolean(1)
#  laverie            :boolean(1)
#  espace_aqua        :boolean(1)
#  club_enfant        :boolean(1)
#  multisport         :boolean(1)
#  loc_velo           :boolean(1)
#  acces_pmr          :boolean(1)
#  animaux            :boolean(1)
#  naturiste          :boolean(1)
#  l_campingqualite   :boolean(1)
#  l_qualitetourisme  :boolean(1)
#  l_tourismehandicap :boolean(1)
#  l_ecotourisme      :boolean(1)
#  l_normandiequalite :boolean(1)
#  l_ancv             :boolean(1)
#  created_at         :datetime        not null
#  updated_at         :datetime        not null
#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as the `Model.where` method doesn't accept an object but only a hash and this hash mustn't contain an id field, what you need to use is this :

```
@query = SearchQuery.where( queryObject.instance_values["attributes"].except("id")      ).first_or_create
```

Where queryObject is the object you need to check the existence of

Thank you davidrac for your help :)

Although I'm kind of disapointed that Rails doesn't come with this built-in, I mean there are so many great things to a lot of tasks quicker than anywhere else and not this ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `first_or_create/first_or_initialize` in order to create an object if there isn't one.

```
query = Query.where(...).first_or_initialize

#do something with the query (increment counter, store parameters)

query.save!
```

Comment: Well the problem with this is when I do Query.where(queryObject), it says I have a TypeError : Cannot visit Query, which I have absolutely no idea what that means

Comment: `@search_query = SearchQuery.where(params[:search_query]).first_or_create`

Comment: what's in params[:search_query]? how does the SearchQuery table look like?

Comment: It's a `SearchQuery` object coming from a `form_for(@search_query)` where `@search_query` is equal to `SearchQuery.new` I'll edit the post to show the table structure

Comment: The TypeError problem is typically related to malformed query parameters. can you dump the actual params hash and share it?

Comment: I have belongs_to relations, isn't there something I should do about it ? What I'm doing is basically go into IRB console `hash = SearchQuery.new` then `hash.save` and `SearchQuery.where(hash)` and then I get the error

Comment: The reason you're getting a type error is that the where condition does not expect an object. see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: Yes, so in theory, `query = SearchQuery.new`, passing `query.instance_values` would solve it given that you're able to remove the `id`. But for some reason, doing `query.instance_values[:attributes]` returns `nil` :/

Comment: Ok, nevermind, it seems that it does'nt accept symbols in that case, could you explain why ? I finally got to what I wanted so I'm going to post it in a clean answer

Answer (score 0):

Rails luckily supports many sweet deals when it comes to validating existing records.

Like the other guys suggest There is an exists method wich you can apply to the data you want to check.

also validates_uniqueness_of is able to validate the record as a whole.

I personally favorite the find_or_create method which can even be chained with more parameters.

Have fun!

Comment: How would you validate the whole record ? My problem here is I can't afford to validate every attribute one by one, I need to pass in my object and see if it's already stored

Comment: In the objects' class you can just add validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :question_id etc. I would advise doing this per parameter just as setting the protection level for mass assignment or assign a unique identifier if you think that's more clean

Answer (score 0):

The best way of doing this is to use `exists?` 
see [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists?/class) for more info.